# How to Return Helpers Text as data from Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a following helper  (below codes are just to demonstrate what I am looking for)

```
@helper SayHello(string text)
{
   @text
}
```

Now from an action i want to return this Helper's Text as Html (or string) as below

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
      //something like this to return just html
      return SayHello("Rusi");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible, but even if so - **PLEASE DO NOT DO THAT!** It so much breaks MVC's separation architecture.

Instead, implement the `SayHello` helper in, say, a .cshtml file which is being called by an action method (you should decorate your action method in a `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute), and then you invoke the action method from within your Razor pages by using `@Html.Action()` or `@Html.RenderAction()`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You can not return a simple string as an actionresult method. Instead you should call your function from ajax and handle the returning text via javascript/jquery. Otherwise you can return a view containig your string like a model. Something like that

```
return View(SayHello("hello world"));
```