# How can i call partial view in my page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, partial-views

I am working on asp.net mvc3 application.
In my application, User can post their comment and at that time i want to display their post in same page using ajax and jquery. This application is like facebook - we can share post, user can comment to post and all.

I have created two actions
- setcomment
-getcomment

how can i do,
- at page load i want to display textarea and post button to post commnent and
- below that all post of the user will be displayed on that
- and user can post subcomments also.

I have my code working but in that i am using actionlink to go to another page and use refresh button to load page again.

---

i have

```
setcomment - 
            @model <NAMESPACE>.<MODELNAME>
            <some code>
 getcomment - 
            @model IEnumerable<<NAMESPACE>.<MODELNAME>>
            <some code>
```

i am not able to call

```
<div id="showusercomments" style="float: left; width: 75%">
    @Html.Partial("_GetUserComment")
 </div>
```

what can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@Html.Action()` instead of Html.Partial .

Also see:

- [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219259/how-to-return-helpers-text-as-data-from-action/7219376#7219376)
- [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968664/asp-net-mvc-2-0-difference-between-renderpartial-and-renderaction/3968700#3968700)

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options:

```
<div id="showusercomments" style="float: left; width: 75%">
    @Html.Action("_GetUserComment")
</div>
```

or, get the `IEnumerable<...>` in the parent page's controller and pass it to the partial:

```
<div id="showusercomments" style="float: left; width: 75%">
    @Html.Partial("_GetUserComment", Model.Comments)
</div>
```